# xevil с anticaptcha выдает ошибку "Connection refused", как исправить?

Tags: python, captcha, xevil

В xevil выбрал разгадывание капч при помощи anticaptcha, запускаю скрипт:

```
from anticaptchaofficial.imagecaptcha import *

solver = imagecaptcha()
solver.set_verbose(1)
solver.set_key(some_key)
captcha_response = solver.solve_and_return_solution(some_path)
```

Получаю следующий ответ:

```
making request to createTask
could not create task
Connection refused
```

Капча ни то, что не решается - соединение в принципе с anticaptcha не устанавливается. Если обращаться напрямую к anticaptcha - все работает корректно. Как решить данный квест?

**EDITED:**

Решил обращаться напрямую к адресу создания задачи на решение капчи:

```
data = {
    'clientKey': ANTI_CAPTCHA_KEY,
    'task': {
        "type": "ImageToTextTask",
        'body': 'screen.png',
        # "numeric": 1,
    }
}
url = 'http://api.anti-captcha.com/createTask'
result = requests.post(url, data)
```

Теперь в ответе такой текст: 'XEVIL INTERNAL ERROR: PROBABLY, INCORRECT REQUEST'

Comment: [anticaptchaofficial](https://pypi.org/project/anticaptchaofficial/), а что у вас в some_path?

Comment: путь к изображению, которое находится в папке с скриптом.

Comment: путь? попробуйте просто название с расширением, если в той же директории?

Comment: Вместо some_path у меня написано: 'screen.png'. Без xevil я получаю даже решение капчи.

Comment: а какое отношение anticaptchaofficial имеет к xevil?

Comment: https://prnt.sc/wmji5k насколько я понял antigate == anticaptchaofficial. Если на сайте antigate.ru тыкнуть на "регистрацию", то редиректит на сайт антикапчи.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import requests
data = {'key': '123'} # Любое число
file = {'file': open('foto.jpg', 'rb'), 'submit': 'Upload and get the ID'}
r = requests.post('http://2captcha.com/in.php', data=data, files=file)
ref = r.text.split('|')[-1]
result = requests.get(f'http://2captcha.com/res.php?key=123&action=get&id={ref}')
res = result.text.split('|')[-1]
print(res)
```

Файл, который отсылаешь в xevil должен лежать в директории скрипта.
В xevil настройках выбираешь 2Captcha